# How to enforce that a property is set that points to a base directory for systemPath?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm trying to enforce that a property is set using the maven enforcer plugin. The property should point to a directory and is used as a base directory for some system scope dependencies. I have the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-systempath</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${non.existent.property}/bar.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-property</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireProperty>
                                    <property>non.existent.property</property>
                                    <message>"non.existent.property" must point to a directory</message>
                                </requireProperty>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now when I run the project with property `non.existent.property` not being set, I get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.example:bar:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${non.existent.property}/bar.jar @ line 14, column 16
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example:maven-enforcer-systempath:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\workingcopy\maven-enforcer-systempath\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.example:bar:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${non.existent.property}/bar.jar @ line 14, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

The reported error appears before the enforcer plugin is invoked. I believe this is because the [documentation of the enforce goal](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html) states:

> Requires dependency collection of artifacts in scope: test.

How can I enforce that the property is set before dependencies are collected?

Comment: Prevent to use system scope dependencies.. Better put the jar into a repository manager and than use it...

Comment: Have you tested that _<systemPath>${non.existent.property}/bar.jar</systemPath>_ works if you set the variable _non.existent.property_ ? In <properties/> for example?

Comment: @pirho yes, I tested this and it works. I just stumbled upon this because a colleague did not have that property set in his local settings and got that error.

Comment: Just to tell that my Eclipse pom editor gives the same error even without running.